# How to understand the graph of a derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, graphing-functions

Let's take a parabolic function $f(x)=x^2$ and its derivative $f'(x)=2x$ and plot them:

[image: plotted parabolic and derivative graph]

In Quadrant 3, the derivative is increasing but negative until it reaches 0. What is meant by *negative* ? It can't be a negative *slope* since the slope is positive.

Also, the slope of the derivative is the same for the entirety of the function, but the parabolic function clearly denotes that the slope is constantly changing. Graphically speaking, how then would the derivative be able to find the tangent points in the parabolic function when it is itself is a linear function of fixed slope ?

Comment: The rate of change of $f'(x)$ isn't negative in the third quadrant. Its rate of change is always $2$.

Comment: You make a confusion between slope and value. The **value** of the derivative is equal to the **slope** of the function at the point. The slope of the derivative does not say anything like that.

Comment: The rate of change of $f'(x)$ is $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Recall that the slope is equal to $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$. The change in $x$ and $y$ is signed, which indicates whether it is decreasing or increasing. Before $x=0$, $x$ is increasing, and $y$ is decreasing. Therefore, the slope, which is equal to the derivative, is negative. This just means it's sloping downwards.
2. The reason the slope graph is linear is because the slope of the derivative graph represents how fast the derivative is changing, not the original function. For a parabola, the derivative changes linearly.
3. The derivative doesn't find the points of tangency. It just shows the slope of the tangent lines at the points of the same $x$ coordinate.

I hope this clears up any confusion. :)

Comment: Very helpful!.Do you mind elaborating on "x is increasing, and y is decreasing" - How is that so ? aren't both x and y  either decreasing or increasing ? Also what is the difference between a point of tangency and the slope of the tangent ?

Comment: @Rijndael In Quadrant 2, as the value of $x$ goes in the positive $x$ direction (i.e. as we go from left to right), the value of $y$ goes in the negative $y$ direction (i.e. it's going down). A point of tangency is where the tangent line actually meets the graph. The slope of the tangent, or the derivative, is the slope of said line.

Comment: Thanks, and what about the difference between a point of tangency and the slope of the tangent ?

Comment: @Rijndael A point of tangency is where the tangent line actually meets the graph. The slope of the tangent, or the derivative, is the slope of said line. The derivative graph is the value of the slope of the tangent at the point on the parabola with the same $x$ coordinate.

Comment: @DavidK Thanks for pointing that mistake out. I changed it.